# How can I get libserial for Raspbian?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, serial, packages

I've got a hard time installing `libserial` on my Raspi 3B with the recent Raspbian: Both [the `libserial` docs](https://libserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/feature_summary.html), and [the Debian package directory](https://packages.debian.org/de/buster/libserial-dev) suggest to install the `libserial-dev` package but a

```
sudo apt-get install libserial-dev
```

says that the package in question doesn't exist. So: Is the information from two different "official" websites wrong, or has the package been revoked or…? Compiling the library from scratch doesn't help either as is doesn't even compile due to a bug in some Python source file. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** This is a list of packages containing `libserial` in their respective names available to me:

```
pi@autoradio:~ $ apt list libserial*
Auflistung... Fertig
libserializer-java/oldoldstable 1.1.6-4 all
libserialport-dev/oldoldstable,now 0.1.0-1 armhf  [installiert]
libserialport0/oldoldstable,now 0.1.0-1 armhf  [Installiert,automatisch]
```

There is a version of `libserial` for Stretch, but apparently not available (any more?). 0.6.0 seems to be not accepted due to an outdated `libc6` and `libstdc++`:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ sudo dpkg -i libserial0_0.6.0_rc2+svn122-4+b11_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 142438 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libserial0_0.6.0_rc2+svn122-4+b11_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libserial0:armhf (0.6.0~rc2+svn122-4+b11) over (0.6.0~rc2+svn122-4+b11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libserial0:armhf:
 libserial0:armhf depends on libc6 (>= 2.28); however:
  Version of libc6:armhf on system is 2.19-18+deb8u10.
 libserial0:armhf depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:armhf on system is 4.9.2-10+deb8u2.

dpkg: error processing package libserial0:armhf (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libserial0:armhf
```

**UPDATE #2:** Maybe I've really got an age-old version of Raspbian:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really time to use Raspbian Buster now. Jessie is deprecated and since beginning of this year it has finished support from Debian. On my Raspbian Buster repository I find:

```
rpi ~$ apt list libserial*
libserial-dev/stable 0.6.0~rc2+svn122-4 armhf
libserial-doc/stable 0.6.0~rc2+svn122-4 all
libserial0/stable 0.6.0~rc2+svn122-4 armhf
libserializer-java/stable 1.1.6-5 all
libserialport-dev/stable 0.1.1-3 armhf
libserialport0/stable 0.1.1-3 armhf
```

All things are available including **libserial-dev**. Maybe you have to use Buster?

Answer (score 2):

You may not run the latest version of Raspbian which is "Buster". I just tested and installed it without any problem.

However, try to install it manually if it doesn't work anyway:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libserial/libserial-dev_0.6.0~rc2+svn122-4+b11_armhf.deb
```

Then:

```
dpkg -i libserial-dev_0.6.0~rc2+svn122-4+b11_armhf.deb
```

[*Source Debian list.*](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libdevel/libserial-dev)

Comment: No use: ``libserial-dev`` depends on ``libserial0``, which itself needs a fairly new (2.28) libc6 and libstdc++ (5.2).

Comment: @Neppomuk Did you try to install `libserial0`, `libc6` and `libstdc++`?

Comment: No use! Too many unfulfilled deps. I'm gonna upgrade my Raspbian installation to Buster now. Seeya soon!